# How to update useRef after redux update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm using useRef to hold the reference of a function that is invoked from a child component (TaskItem) when it is clicked on:

UserTask -> TaskList -> TaskItem

```
// UserTask.js

const [detailsVisible, setDetailsVisible] = useState(false)
const [selectedTask, setSelectedTask] = useState({})

const openTask = (id) =>{
    const task = props.tasks.find(task => task.id === id);
    setDetailsVisible(true);
    setSelectedTask(task);
}

const openTaskRef = useRef(openTask);
const openTaskHandler = useCallback(id =>{
    openTaskRef.current(id);
}, []);

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <TaskList 
            tasks={props.tasks} 
            onClick={openTaskHandler}
        />

        <Modal visible={detailsVisible} onClose={()=> setDetailsVisible(false)}>
            <Comments items={selectedTask.comments || []} />
        </Modal>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

The list of tasks arrives via redux->props a few seconds after they are fetched from an API:

```
// Still UserTask.js

useEffect(()=>{
    fetchTasks()
}, [fetchTasks])

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return {
        fetchTasks: ()=> dispatch(fetchTasks())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserTasks)
```

Now, my problem is that when the component (UserTask) is rendered the first time, the 'openTaskRef' gets created with a context in which props.tasks is empty (since the API request hasn't been issued yet). I need to use the useRef/useCallback combination to avoid re-rendering of TaskItems when the props.tasks list is updated after an item is removed (a scenario not described in the code above).

How can I control this scenario? How can I update the reference to openTask to include the most recent list of tasks?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't quite understand why useRef is used at all here. If the choice of which function to invoke is made in the child component, why not simply pass a callback through via props? And why do you *need* to avoid the re-rendering? If an item is removed, the other ones won't hit the DOM if they haven't changed their markup, since this is React.

Comment: @timotgl, after an item is removed, and the UserTask props.tasks is updated, it forces that parent component to re-render; if I just pass a function via props to TaskList -> TaskItem, since the callback function is redefined every single time UserTask renders, this causes ALL the child components to re-render, regardless of whether the objects inside the tasks array persist or not. That's the reason why I'm using useRef and useCallback, to keep the reference to the function unchanged between renders.